# PHP Magento 2 OAuth Issue

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I have been using [PHPoAuthLIb](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib). I do not why I do not get 404 request on oauth related any url.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuth\Common\Http\Exception\TokenResponseException' with message 'file_get_contents(http://localhost:8082/eam/oauth/initiate): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ' in C:\wamp\www\Mage\OAuthLib\src\OAuth\Common\Http\Client\StreamClient.php on line 73

Comment: Could you please provide your code as well.

Comment: Here is the code- https://github.com/observo/MageOAuth/blob/master/examples/magento.php